# .gdb folder to map use for Garmin gps

Tags: file-geodatabase, garmin

My government provides maps that I thought I could use on my Garmin eTrax 20. 
They come as a .gdb folder with these files inside. This is a N50 map over a state(Norway) if that matters.

`a00000001.TablesByName.atx
a00000001.gdbindexes
a00000001.gdbtable
a00000001.gdbtablx
a00000002.gdbtable
a00000002.gdbtablx
a00000003.gdbindexes
a00000003.gdbtable
a00000003.gdbtablx
a00000004.CatItemsByPhysicalName.atx
a00000004.CatItemsByType.atx
a00000004.FDO_UUID.atx
a00000004.freelist
a00000004.gdbindexes
a00000004.gdbtable
a00000004.gdbtablx
a00000004.spx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByName.atx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByParentTypeID.atx
a00000005.CatItemTypesByUUID.atx
a00000005.gdbindexes
a00000005.gdbtable
a00000005.gdbtablx
a00000006.CatRelsByDestinationID.atx
a00000006.CatRelsByOriginID.atx
a00000006.CatRelsByType.atx
a00000006.FDO_UUID.atx
a00000006.gdbindexes
a00000006.gdbtable
a00000006.gdbtablx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByBackwardLabel.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByDestItemTypeID.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByForwardLabel.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByName.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByOriginItemTypeID.atx
a00000007.CatRelTypesByUUID.atx
a00000007.gdbindexes
a00000007.gdbtable
a00000007.gdbtablx
a00000009.freelist
a00000009.gdbindexes
a00000009.gdbtable
a00000009.gdbtablx
a00000009.spx
a0000000a.freelist
a0000000a.gdbindexes
a0000000a.gdbtable
a0000000a.gdbtablx
a0000000a.spx
a0000000b.freelist
a0000000b.gdbindexes
a0000000b.gdbtable
a0000000b.gdbtablx
a0000000b.spx
a0000000c.freelist
a0000000c.gdbindexes
a0000000c.gdbtable
a0000000c.gdbtablx
a0000000c.spx
a0000000d.freelist
a0000000d.gdbindexes
a0000000d.gdbtable
a0000000d.gdbtablx
a0000000d.spx
a0000000e.freelist
a0000000e.gdbindexes
a0000000e.gdbtable
a0000000e.gdbtablx
a0000000e.spx
a0000000f.gdbindexes
a0000000f.gdbtable
a0000000f.gdbtablx
a0000000f.spx
a00000010.freelist
a00000010.gdbindexes
a00000010.gdbtable
a00000010.gdbtablx
a00000010.spx
a00000011.freelist
a00000011.gdbindexes
a00000011.gdbtable
a00000011.gdbtablx
a00000011.spx
a00000012.freelist
a00000012.gdbindexes
a00000012.gdbtable
a00000012.gdbtablx
a00000012.spx
a00000013.gdbindexes
a00000013.gdbtable
a00000013.gdbtablx
a00000013.spx
a00000014.freelist
a00000014.gdbindexes
a00000014.gdbtable
a00000014.gdbtablx
a00000014.spx
a00000015.freelist
a00000015.gdbindexes
a00000015.gdbtable
a00000015.gdbtablx
a00000015.spx
a00000016.gdbindexes
a00000016.gdbtable
a00000016.gdbtablx
a00000016.spx
a00000017.freelist
a00000017.gdbindexes
a00000017.gdbtable
a00000017.gdbtablx
a00000017.spx
a00000018.gdbindexes
a00000018.gdbtable
a00000018.gdbtablx
a00000018.spx
a00000019.AnnoClassID_Index_23.atx
a00000019.Status_Index_23.atx
a00000019.gdbindexes
a00000019.gdbtable
a00000019.gdbtablx
a00000019.spx
files.txt
gdb
timestamps`

I tried using Basecamp from Garmin but it seems to only acceps .gdb as a file, not a folder.

Is there a way I can make this into something Basecamp or Garmin eTrax 20 accepts?

**Edit:**

BaseCamp accepts these formats. But eTrax might not accept them. I dont know.
[image: Accepted file formats]

**Edit 2:**

Error when opening .gdx file in BaseCamp:
[image: Unknown Error]

**Edit 3:**

Here's my procedure:

[image: Choosing all layers]

Then I select all layers.
[image: Select all layers]
And eksport the layers[image: exporting layers]

Here I tried GPX without that ended with an error in BaseCamp

Tried KML which did work in BaseCamp but I only got markup for houses.
[image: Markup for houses]

**Edit 4:**

I have learned until now that i do have what is called "ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB)". The goal is still to have this transfered over to the Garmin gps.

I gave @AndreJ answer below a shot, but failed.

I attempted to use gdal(ogr2ogr) to convert fgdb dataset to osm and garmin gdb. It started processing, but I got some errors with field names not supported and some errors when writing.

> GDAL is basically able to convert between the both by the use of the GPSBABEL driver.

I tried that using this command:

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f "GPSBabel" GPSBabel:gdb:outMapGarmin Basisdata_05_Oppland_25832_N50Kartdata_FGDB.gdb
```

[image: Zero size file created]

I pasted the errors here: [errors on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4AHHatBn)

> If you are interested in polygons, you might think of converting the data to .osm format and render a GARMIN map with mkgmap.

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f GPSBabel GPSBabel:osm:outmap.osm Basisdata_05_Oppland_25832_N50Kartdata_FGDB.gdb
```

I pasted the errors here: [errors on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/QiWcdJyq)

I wonder if I'm doing it wrong or is there some other way?

Comment: Do you have Arc Desktop?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: If you can download QGIS you can open the gdb and export feature to shape, and then I think that you can open a .shp file in your Garmin device. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8isLE6yo3s0

Comment: @enolan I think that video uses ArcMap...

Comment: It does but it also shows how to use a .shp file in a garmin device.

Comment: I don't believe my Garmin device supports .shc format

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking two data formats that use the same extension:

- ESRI FileGDB can be used by GDAL and QGIS
- GARMIN GDB can be used in Base Camp and Garmin GPS devices

GDAL is basically able to convert between the both by the use of the [GPSBABEL driver](https://www.gdal.org/drv_gpsbabel.html).

But the driver uses [GPX](https://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html) as an intermediate format, so the restrictions of that format apply to the GPSBabel output as well. The main obstacles are the absent of polygon, multiline and multipoint geometry types, and the limited allowed field names. You can use QGIS to sanitize your data with `polygon to line` and `multipart to single part` conversion. The output should be in EPSG:4326.

If you are interested in polygons, you might think of converting the data to .osm format and render a Garmin .img map with mkgmap. In QGIS you can transform your data to shapefile, and load that into the JOSM editor to apply tags like `building=yes` or `landuse=forest`. Save it to a .osm file, **AND DO NOT UPLOAD TO THE OSM SERVER** on exit.

Some Garmin devices allow .kmz files with georeferenced images to be loaded. QGIS can create georeferenced .jpg images with `Save as image`. Make sure to work in EPSG:4326 as project CRS. https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GarminCustomMap/ , https://www.maptiler.com/blog/2009/10/garmin-custom-maps-kmz-from-geotiff-via.html  and https://support.maptiler.com/i80-import-custom-maps-to-garmin-gps might be worth to explore as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll check this out when I got time and reply with result

Comment: see my edit 4 for trying your suggestion, I think I'm doing it wrong, could you explain?

Comment: You are hitting the restrictions of the GPX format: No polygons, and only very restricted field names. You could use QGIS to convert polygons into closed lines, and remove fields you don't need in the attribute table. For the conversion to osm, I thought of https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ogr2osm instead of the GPSBabel driver.

Comment: Seems that this is more difficult than I originally thought. I do have other formats of the same data that might be better to work with (FGDB,PostGIS, GML, SOSI). Do you know if any of them is worth another shot? Will try conversion to osm soon

Comment: The bottleneck is still the same on the garmin side.

Answer (score 0):

With QGIS, you can open the Geodatabase using the Layer > Add Layer > Add Vector Layer with the following settings:

[image]

From there, you can right-click the layer, then SAVE AS a format such as GPX that your Garmin will support (not sure what other formats you might have available with that unit).

Comment: Seems to almost work. I get an error when importing to BaseCamp. See updated question.

Comment: Wait - it says that it takes GDB files - can you just upload the GDB you got originally?

Comment: It takes gdb files. But not a folder like I have. Or can I save it as a file?

Comment: @Starlord I see I see... I can't remember how QGIS exports back to GDB but there has to be a better format for you... Also: what layers from the GDB are you trying to import into Basecamp?

Comment: I'm hoping to take all the layers with me. I realize that when using the KML format qgis did just select one layer. I'm in the process of merging, but I have polygon layer and line layer which I need to reproject first.

Comment: I want to make it a map to replace the one on the GPS. The one that is there have no details at all.

Comment: @Starlord not having access to this software/hardware, I'm a bit confused as to what it says it can do with a GDB - which is at least at the file system level a 'folder' of stuff - it is still a collection of layers that Basecamp should be able to read as a whole... I might be out of ideas...

Comment: @Starlord I'm not familiar with the Garmin app that you are trying to utilize but sometimes with applications that are looking for .gdbs and .shps the browse tool just want you to select the .gdb and not double click it. If you do it will require you to open it. a gdb is a folder of files that are all related to the file geodatabase. I don't see how it can be one file. If it was the indexing and locks etc wouldn't work as designed.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I too think gdb should work, might open a support ticket to Garmin soon.

Answer (score 0):

Global Mapper reads ESRI FileGeoDatabase and can write to Garmin File Formats

Answer (score 0):

I would open the .gdb file in QGIS, save as a shapefile, open the shapefile in JOSM, save as an .osm file and then use mkgmap (and splitter) to output a Garmin .img file

It would interesting to see the difference between the original and final display.